# Kafka producer timeout issues

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am looking for some clarification regarding properties which we can be used to avoid producer timeout due to either more time taken since batch creation with blocked batch or timeout with metadata read. I am confused if I should increase max.block.ms or delivery.timeout.ms?? And if we also need to set buffer.memory with these timeouts to avoid blockage with memory issue??

I am using spring kafka template send method to produce message with defined producer properties bean.

Comment: There is a [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=66851583) describe the meaning of different timeouts. For you question, I think we need more information to decide which one should be increased. Or you can increase one each time to see which solve the problem.

Comment: @haoyu can you please let me know what information should I add here for further inputs ? Thanks